# Java XML API converts &quot; to &amp;quot;

Tags: java, xml, character-encoding

I am developing a Java program that reads HTML code, parses the HTML, gets the content (human-readable text) and stores it in a XML file. Sometimes, the HTML code contains `'`, `"` characters (among others), but sometimes they're also written as `&apos;` and `&quot;` respectively.

I build the XML following the appropriate procedure. I use the `Document` and `Element` classes, and I make the XML file using the `Transformer`, `DomSource` and `StreamResult` classes.

The problem is that when the file is saved, I see that the `&` symbol is replaced with a `&amp;`. I know that's the right thing. But it converts `&apos;` to `&amp;&apos` as well!

I have also tried to convert the `Document` object to a `String` object, and then pass that string to `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(String s)` method, to leave the XML entities intact. However, it does not convert the `&` entity to `&amp;`, resulting in an invalid XML file.

(I have set the `OutputKeys.ENCODING` to "UTF-8" and the `OutputKeys.METHOD` to "xml".)

Comment: I suspect that you are writing a string containing the six characters `& a p o s ;` to a text node in a DOM document, so that the text node gets serialized as `& a m p ; a p o s ;`. The text node should contain unescaped text (that is, a single character `'`) and the serializer will decide whether to escape it or not.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your HTML parsing, not with your XML output. In HTML &apos; is a single quote, so when there is &apos; in the HTML your parser should give it to you as a single quote.

What parser are you using? Popular parsers such as Jsoup don't make that error.

Comment: That's not the problem. I don't mind if I have either `&apos;` or `'`. I think the problem is when the XML parser sees the `&` symbol without noticing that there is followed by a `apos;` or `quot;` etc, therefore converting it to `&amp;`, thus having `&amp;quot;`. However, if text was "George & Nick", of course the `&` should be converted to `&amp;`.

Comment: Yes it is the problem, no the XML serializer doesn't make that mistake. I don't know why you think that despite being pointed out otherwise, but that is an incorrect thought.